# JavaFX Alert Dialog Cancel Button

Tags: java, javafx

I made a JavaFX alert dialog box to prompt the user, asking if they want to save the output from the console before closing the application.

I have the yes and no options taken care of. If the user clicks cancel, I want it to just close the dialog box and leave everything open. As of right now, if I hit cancel it will close the GUI.

Here is my code for overriding the close button on the GUI.

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event)
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Warning");
            alert.setHeaderText("Would You Like To Save Your Console Output?");
            alert.setContentText("Please choose an option.");

            ButtonType yesButton = new ButtonType("Yes");
            ButtonType noButton = new ButtonType("No");
            ButtonType cancelButton = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

            alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(yesButton, noButton, cancelButton);

            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if(result.get() == yesButton)
            {
                Main.setConsoleVisible();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            }
            else if(result.get() == noButton)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if(result.get() == cancelButton)
            {

            }  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try placing a print statement within each button type case, is the cancel one definitely being called?

Comment: Additionally I think the more traditional way to create button types is to use the ButtonType class built-ins i.e. `ButtonType yesButton = ButtonType.YES`

Comment: ButtonType yesButton = ButtonType.YES does not work. I did put a print statement inside of the else if cancelButton and it does print my message.

Comment: you could try comparing the getButtonData() result rather than the ButtonType objects themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for onCloseRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty):

> Called when there is an external request to close this Window. The installed event handler can prevent window closing by consuming the received event.

Be aware that `result.get()` will throw an exception if the user closes the alert dialog without pressing any buttons.  The [Dialog documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) explains this thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Both in "yesButton" and "cancelButton" if-blocks consume the CloseRequest `WindowEvent`:

```
else if(result.get() == cancelButton)
{
    event.consume();
}
```

Use `Platform.exit()` instead of `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Thanks! I had two problems going on, one of them was I was too "deep" into my GUI. I had to go up one more level to my main scene. Then event.consume() worked as intended :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `primaryStage.close();` instead of `System.exit(0);`